# cannot view the database image into the table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I cannot view my image in the table which name is store in the database.It shows broken image even though the image is correct.

```
<td><img id="img" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $rows->customer_image;?>" width="30px" height="30px"/></td>.
```

Comment: Have you set the base url in config.php make sure not blank

Comment: yes it solve the problem...but why we should put the base url...even though the codeigniter automatically track it ....is'nt it?

Comment: If you using codeigniter 3 you should read the comment above it. It will explain it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check on your `base_url`, is has correct value or not ?
2. Replace from your `src` value into this (more readable) :

`<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$rows->customer_image); ?>`

3. Check your database as well as image in your `uploads` directory, is exist or not ?

Additional note : use `alt` attribute in your `img` element for giving text if your image won't appear. Hope it helps